# git clone doesn't work for me between two systems, why?

Tags: git-clone

I have two systems and LAN connection is their between them.

- `System1`: Here I create a bare repository named with `project.git` in `c:/directory` and store all my files in it.
  The system1's IP address is 192.168.1.8
- `System2`: There, I try to clone the system1's bare repository using the command

  ```
  git clone file:////192.168.1.8/c/project.git
  ```

But it doesn't worked out. It gives the error like:

```
cloning into project......
fatal: '192.168.1.8/c/Users/Admin/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository.
fatal: could not read from remote repository"
```

What I tried: I worked out these below commands, but I didn't get the answer:

```
git clone file:////192.168.1.8/project
git clone file:////192.168.1.8/c/project**
```

How would you do that `git clone`?

Comment: Did you already set-up the ssh keys?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you split the issue:

- first, assign a drive letter to a share folder:

  ```
  net use w: \\192.168.1.8\c$
  ```
- then use that local path

  ```
  git clone w:\directory\project.git
  # or
  git clone file://w:/directory/project.git
  ```

The first point ensures that you have access to the distant repo through Windows filesystem (independently of git): that is the first issue you need to solve.
Once you can do a dir, *then* you can try a `git clone` through filesystem.

The second point allows for the `git clone` to proceed.